# OpenShift online - OutOfMemory on build

Tags: java, docker, openshift

In these days I started to play with OpenShift online.
I deployed a very simple "Hello World" Java example (1 line of code!) without any dependency (No Spring!)
The command line is something like this:

```
 oc.exe new-app registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift~<GIT URL> --context-dir=demo-docker --name=demo-docker
```

The builds ALWAYS fails with OOM error.
How is it possibile?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [Build Resources](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/advanced_build_operations.html#build-resources). To understand the difference between `requests` and `limits`, the [Compute Resources](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/compute_resources.html#dev-compute-resources) will provide that information.

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "BuildConfig"
metadata:
  name: "sample-build"
spec:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: "100m" 
      memory: "256Mi"
    requests: 
      cpu: "100m"
      memory: "256Mi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it is necessary to set more memory on build process with

```
oc.exe  patch bc/demo-docker --patch "{\"spec\":{\"resources\":{\"limits\":{\"memory\":\"1Gi\"}}}}"
```

It is quite incredible that default value is so low.